# Goldfish in a lake

Tags: statistics

It is known that many people dump their pet goldfish into lakes, when they want to get rid of them with no remorse!
We wish to calculate the number of goldfish in a small lake, in which there are several other fish of various species.
For this purpose we pick 20 goldfish and put them a permanent mark and then release them into the lake. After one day (and assuming there are no changes in the population of goldfish or other fish – the system is “closed”), we pick 30 goldfish, of which 5 are found marked. What is the probability that the total population of goldfish in the lake is from 115 to 125?

> I have found that this is done by using the “mark and recapture” method, by which we calculate the expected population to be

$\frac{20*30}{5} = 120$

But how do we calculate the probability for it to be in the requested range?

Of course by intuition, I guess it must be close to 100%!

Comment: I have an idea: This can be seen as estimating the parameter $p$ in a repeated Bernoulli-distributed trial! The proportion of fish that are marked is equal to $p$ (it's actually equal to $\frac{\text{20}}{\text{something}}$), we do 30 trials and we have 5 successes. So now it's a matter of estimating $p$.

Comment: If you take $X$ to be the number of marked fish that were recaptured, then an estimator of total population is $\hat N=\frac{20\times 30}{X}$ where $X$ can be assumed to have a hypergeometric distribution (for sampling without replacement). Observed value of $\hat N$ is indeed 120 which is an estimate of total population.

Comment: Lincoln–Petersen method. Well done, but don't know about the probability.

Comment: L-P method is problematic. Makes no sense to speak of unbiasedness bc/ L-P provides no probability dist'n. It's possible to get $k=0$ unmarked fish upon resample. (That's one reason for Chapman method.) To put a proper dist'n on $N$ as a _rand var_ instead of a _parameter_ to be estimated, we need a Bayesian framework, alluded to but not developed in Wikipedia article. Lacking that, @StubbornAtom mentions the only reasonable ans: $k=5$ is only $k$ with $115 \le \hat N \le 125,$ so we must have $k=5.$ Your intuition $\approx 100\%$ looks good. // In R, `phyper(5, 20,100, 30)` returns 0.6222.

Answer (score 1):

Your question

> What is the probability that the total population of goldfish in the lake is from $115$ to $125$?

is only meaningful from a Bayesian perspective.

Your experiment tells you that the population is at least $45$ as you know there are $20$ marked fish and at least the $30-5=25$ unmarked fish you found.

To use a Bayesian calculation, you need a prior distribution for the population, and this will affect your calculated posterior probability based on the observation.  For example using R

- with an improper prior probability that is constant (i.e. just looking at sums of likelihoods) you could try

```
    sum(dhyper(5, 20, (115:125) - 20, 30) * 1) / 
    sum(dhyper(5, 20, (45:10^6) - 20, 30) * 1)
    # 0.08099914
```

- with an proper prior probability of the population being  $N$ is proportional to $\frac{1}{N^2}$, you could try

```
    sum(dhyper(5, 20, (115:125) - 20, 30) * 1/(115:125)^2) / 
    sum(dhyper(5, 20, (45:10^6) - 20, 30) * 1/(45:10^6)^2)
    # 0.1072485
```

which suggests that your guess that the probability the population is in that range "must be close to $100\%$" is far too high. Even if you were absolutely sure there were in fact say between $100$ and $150$ fish in the pond, so replacing `45` by `100` and replacing `10^6` by `150`, the calculated probabilities for the range would still be relatively low.